# Cannot restore topmost window from window menu (OSX)

Tags: macos, cocoa

I create a window and set level to NSStatusWindowLevel. In Dock Preferences, I enable "Minimize windows into application". After I minimize the window into dock icon, the window disappears when I select it (to restore) from window menu.

My OS X version is 10.11. When I try on OS X 10.6, it works fine.

Is this a bug of Cocoa? How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: I never faced this. My application runs on 10.7 through 10.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I overcome this issue by this trick:

1. Before miniaturize, set window level to NSNormalWindowLevel
2. Observe NSWindowDidDeminiaturize notification
3. Restore window level to NSStatusWindowLevel in notification handler.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try. This is a horrible bug on Apple's part - if you click on it a few times and wait a few seconds, the app actually does eventually show up (10-30s delay). My guess is that OSX is deferring some of the window rendering in some cases.